# disable jQuery slider plugin if not enough content

Tags: jquery, plugins, slider

I'm currently using [this](http://jivstudio.com/2008/12/20/show-partial-content-slide-animate-with-jquery/) jQuery plugin for expanding / collapsing my textboxes.
[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/984h8/) the jsFiddle of it.

What I would like to do is the following: 
when the content of the `.slider` is smaller than the the variable `sliderHeight` the plugin shouldn't even run aka you shouldn't be able to expand or collapse the the textbox.

What would be the best way to do it?